# Как пронумеровать строки в шаблонизаторе twig?

Tags: twig, php

Добрый день. Подскажите, как  пронумеровать строки в шаблонизаторе twig?
Я вывожу данные в таблицу и хочу каждую строку пронумеровать.
Спасибо.

Comment: `for line_index, line in lines` не работает?

Comment: Я вывожу данные в таблицу и хочу каждую строку пронумеровать.
___
Про phpstorm я знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно проще:

```
{% for item in array %}
    {{ loop.index }} - с единицы считает
    {{ loop.index0 }} - с нуля выводит
{% endfor%}
```

Тут подробнее можете посмотреть http://x-twig.ru/tags/for/

Answer (score 0):

```
Разобрался:

{% set i = 0 %}
  цикл
{% set i = i +1 %}
{{i}}
```